# Is a plist or NSUserDefaults More Efficient for storing a small amount of data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsuserdefaults

I can go either way on this for this project, but I'm curious if using a plist to store some data is going to be more or less efficient than just keeping a plist in the documents folder. The data is about 50 strings/dictionaries.

In both cases the data gets persisted using some file IO so disk access should be similar.

However, the plist seems like a little more work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSUserDefaults *is* a plist (that is why only plist types can be stored in it). So ultimately there isn't going to be much difference in efficiency (whatever you mean by that). Your consideration should rather be where it is *appropriate* to keep this data. Don't keep it in the Document folder unless it is appropriate for storage in iCloud, says Apple; it will be backed up when the user backs up the device, and will subtract from the user's quota, so you need to be sparing of what you keep there.

In one of my own apps, where I download a bunch of data from an RSS feed and present it to the user, I store the data in the user defaults, because it is part of the app's persistent state the next time it appears. My data isn't a document; it's the app's state. That's my reasoning, and I'd suggest you might reason along similar lines...

Comment: I'm storing even less data than your RSS feed example. So it sounds like NSUserDefaults might be an easier call. By "efficient" I'm thinking about speed to return the data, and memory taken up by data that is not needed at this time.

Comment: And what if you want your RSS feed data synchronized with other devices through iCloud? Is there any difference or would you still go for NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, plist are much simpler to use than NSuserDefaults.  Afterall, a dictionary can save itself as a plist.  As for efficiency, they sould be the same as NSUserDefaults stores everything as a plist but provides more services such as comparing which key/values pair have changed compared to a provided set of key/values default pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider JSON using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/wiki/Performance). Some tests show it's [faster than a binary plist](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/), if speed is your primary concern. The API is dead simple because it creates a category on `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. Calling `-(NSData *)JSONData` on either of those objects returns an `NSData` object ready to save.