# How to save data from ViewController and Load it to TableViewController when app rerun?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a class "WishListItem", a TableViewController and a ViewController. I'm having difficulties in saving chunk of data and retrieving it from TableViewController? How to do this effectively?

Here's my ViewController which has a prepareForSegue that stores data to my WishListItem class.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSDate *myDate = self.targetDatePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
    NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

    if (sender != self.addWishListButton) return;
    if (self.wishTextField.text.length > 0) {
        self.wishItem = [[WishlistItem alloc] init];
        self.wishItem.wishlistItem  = self.wishTextField.text;
        self.wishItem.descWishItem = self.descTextField.text;
        self.wishItem.targetDate = prettyVersion;
    }
}
```

WishListItem.h :

```
@interface WishlistItem : NSObject

@property NSString *wishlistItem;
@property NSString *descWishItem;
@property NSString *targetDate;

@end
```

ViewController.h :

```
@interface JLSViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *addWishListButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *wishTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *targetDatePicker;

@property WishlistItem *wishItem;

@end
```

From here. I want to save it every time I add a wishItem. How would I store MULTIPLE ENTRIES? and at the same time retrieve those entries in my TableViewController?

Please let me know if I need to provide more info. TIA.

Comment: How much data that you potentially need to store or retrieve in your tableview? If it has very little data, you can use NSUserDefaults. If it has some reasonable amount, you can try PList. If it is a lot, you can try Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and the rude way of doing it is storing the data in NSUserDefaults

```
+(void)userDefaultsSetObject:(id)userObject forKey:(NSString *)userKey
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:userObject forKey:userKey];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

/**
 *  This method helps to get values from NSUserDefaults
 */

+(id)userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:(NSString *)userKey
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults objectForKey:userKey];
}
```

Use the above two functions to save and retrieve data from NSUserDefaults. So coming to your problem here, add the wishlistitem objects to an array and set it in NSUserDefaults. Add this code to your tableviewcontroller class, and have a datasource array as a global variable.

```
 NSMutableArray *dataSourceArray;
```

In ViewDidLoad of the tableviewcontroller class add this,

```
NSMutableArray *wishlistItems;

if([self userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:@"WishListItems"]==nil)
{
  wishlistItems = [NSMutableArray array];
}
else
{
   wishlistItems = [self userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:@"WishListItems"];
}

dataSourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:wishlistItems];
```

And in the tableViewDelegateMethod, try this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dataSourceArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    WishlistItem *wishListObject = [dataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:wishListObject.wishlistItem];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:wishListObject.descWishItem];
    return cell;
}
```

So every time you add something do this,

```
- (NSMutableArray*)wishListAdded:(WishlistItem*)wishList
{
   NSMutableArray *wishlistItems;

   if([self userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:@"WishListItems"]==nil)
   {
     wishlistItems = [NSMutableArray array];
     [wishlistItems addObject: wishItem];
     [self userDefaultsSetObject:wishlistItems forKey:@"WishListItems"];
   }
   else
   {
     wishlistItems = [self userDefaultsGetObjectForKey:@"WishListItems"];
     [wishlistItems addObject:yourWishListObject];
     [self userDefaultsSetObject:wishlistItems forKey:@"WishListItems"];
    }
    return wishlistItems;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @satheeshwaran, i'll try your instruction. I hope I could make this work. Getting frustrated with this already. :(

Comment: Hi @satheeshwaran, can you help me regarding this? How should I save data from my ViewController and retrieve it on my TableViewController? Thanks..

Comment: @Rhenzzz Dude everytime you add something save append that item to the  array we store in userdefaults and then everytime you load the tableview fetch values from userdefaults and use that as the data source.

Answer (score 1):

To save your array state use this ie in view controller

```
NSString *valueToSave = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

use this where you want to retrieve the variable ie. intableViewController

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

Comment: Hi can you help me more how should I implement this? I'm not that good yet at programming in iOS. Thanks

Comment: you can search in google that how to save app state using NSUserDefault. @Rhenzzz

Answer (score 1):

You can use mutablearrays for saving multiple objects of your wishlist class and then store that array in the userdefaults and retrieve it as per your needs.

Any changes made to the a particular object in the index of the array needs to be updated in the user default as well, else you will end up getting the same result set which you have stored in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create the `@property WishlistItem *wishItem;` object in TableViewController .h file and save all the data while in segue method. So this is how your implementation will look like

in `TableViewController.h`

```
#import "WishlistItem.h"

@interface SomeTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property WishlistItem *wishItem
```

in `JLSViewController.m`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSDate *myDate = self.targetDatePicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
    NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

    if (sender != self.addWishListButton) return;
    if (self.wishTextField.text.length > 0) {
       SomeTableViewController *tableViewController = [segue destinationViewController]; 
       tableViewController.wishItem = [[WishlistItem alloc] init];
       tableViewController.wishItem.wishlistItem  = self.wishTextField.text;
       tableViewController.wishItem.descWishItem = self.descTextField.text;
       tableViewController.wishItem.targetDate = prettyVersion;
    }
}
```

in TableViewController.m

you can populate the data in tableview using `self.wishItem.wishlistItem` etc.

if you want to save large data then consider using Core Data, also NSDateFormatter is expensive operation so you can refer this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#reuseobjects) for some improving that.

Comment: Hi can you help me more how should I implement this? I'm not that good yet at programming in iOS. Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried the changes suggested above for wishItem class in tableViewController?

Comment: I don't quite get this? It's looks like the same as my previous implementation. I would like to try to save those data so when the app reruns the simple data wont get erased/lost.

Comment: then you need to use core data or try NSUserDefaults.

Comment: I'm thinking of using core data also. Is it easy to use? I just want only to store strings and store it to my tableviewcontroller when the app reruns. i'm having difficulties in using NSUserDefaults. :(

Comment: go through these tutorials http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/ and http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started or refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

There are severals ways of saving data and retrieving them:

**1. Saving data to NSUserDefaults** (how Anonymous suggested):
With NSUserDefaults you can save objects from the following class types:
NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary
try to take a look at the documentation, UserDefaults is simple to understand and use.
[NSUserDefaults Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**2. Saving data to Property List file (plist)**
It is kind of the same like UserDefaults (it can store the same data type) difference is you write your data in a document.
But: Don't keep it in the Document folder unless it is appropriate for storage in iCloud, says Apple;  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004039/3593011)

**3. Save data to a data base**
this will be another way to store your data...

At the end it all depends how complex will be the data you want to save, are we talking about strings and numbers or images NSUserNotification etc

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSDate *myDate = self.targetDatePicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];

if (sender != self.addWishListButton) return;
if (self.wishTextField.text.length > 0) 
{
       NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:self.wishTextField.text forKey:@"wishTextField"];
    [dict setObject:self.descTextField.text forKey:@"descTextField"];
    [dict setObject:prettyVersion forKey:@"prettyVersion"];
    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"myWishList"];
//check if array is not null i`m not sure if it will give you error if it is null
// if null NSMutableArray *array= [NSMutableArray alloc]init]; else             
    [array addObject:dict];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    [userDefaults setObject:array forKey:@"myWishList"];

}
}
```

i think this should work for saving. For loading data in your:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // methode 
//add this
 NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"myWishList"];
// this will return all your wishlist items
  NSMutableDictionary *dict =  [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// this will give you the data you saved in the particular place 
 cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"wishTextField"];//this will be the name of the whishlist
```

I think this should do

Comment: Hi can you help me more how should I implement this?

Comment: I just didn't understand where I should implement the extraction of data for it to display on my TableViewController.

Comment: You sad that you have a tableViewController so in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
for example: `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [userDefaults objectForKey:indexPath.row]; cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"wishListItem"];` this will return the wishlistitem and will set the cell label name to the whishlistitem