# Using Realm data as application settings

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a a Realm Class called 'Settings' with a primary key of 'Settings'. This way I will only have one record in the Settings Realm. The Settings class contains several variables (I.e showDetailedCell (bool), username (string), appColor (string)) that I need to access several times in the app's lifecycle. They also have to stay up to date. For instance. I have a tableView that displays detailed information in the cells if showDetailedCell is true. If the user turns this off in settings the tableview should be updated with the newly set value. This is how I do it now to make sure I always have the latest value, but I believe it is not very efficient:

```
var _generalSettings : Settings?
var generalSettings : Settings? {
    get {

        if self._generalSettings == nil || self._generalSettings?.isInvalidated == true {

            self._generalSettings = try? Settings.getNewOrExisting().object
        }

        self._generalSettings?.realm?.refresh()

        return self._generalSettings
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> RosterCell {

    //Create the cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell

   let showDetailed = generalSettings?.showDetailedCell ?? true

   cell.setupAsDetailed = showDetailed

    return cell

}
```

What would be the best way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have just gone for [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

> An interface to the user's defaults database, where you store
>   key-value pairs persistently across invocations of your app on a given
>   device.

Storing data using `UserDefaults` (.plist) will be a bit costly for users as if they back up the device, [the data stored in Document folder will also be backed up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004039/7113238), from @matt. However, if you want to save the app's state, you should go for `UserDefaults` as it will be synced among users' devices via iCloud.

> An app can use the iCloud key-value store to share small amounts of
>   data with other instances of itself on the user’s other computers and
>   iOS devices. For example, a magazine app might store the current issue
>   and page number being read by the user so that other instances of the
>   app can open to the same page when launched.

```
// Set User Preference
UserDefaults.standard.set("VALUE", forKey: "KEY")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

// Get User Preference
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "KEY")
```

Comment: I agree, for storing such simple values and storing only a single instance of the model class, UserDefaults seems a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I used UserDefaults before I implemented Realm and it worked fine. I switched the same time I started using Realm for the larger databases as it was so easy to troubleshoot bugs by including the Settings realm in the feedback email from the user. I also saw some delay (getting and setting values) when I synchronized the UserDefaults that I have not seen with Realm. I'll consider switching back if that's the recommended approach! Thanks!

Comment: @fisher well, if you already experimented with both methods and you found Realm to be faster then stick with it. In general, UserDefaults should be easier to use for such a simple model and could also be faster, but if for you Realm was faster and it's also easier to use, than you shouldn't change from this approach.

Comment: A big advantage of using `UserDefaults` is when you want to save the app's state. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. They will help me making my final decision. Let's say I continue with the Realm approach. What is would be the best practice to access the variables in my use case in your opinion? Should I initialize a new Realm every time? The reson I am now doing the way described in my original post is because I sometimes did not get the correct values I the variables had been changed in a different thread. By refreshing the realm every time before accessing the variables I always got the updated value.

Comment: Realm is not thread safe and cannot be shared across thread, so your must create a Realm instance at least once in each thread. Creating a Realm every time will help you avoid the problem with thread, and don't worry about memory usage issues as a Realm file object is only created once on each thread, and "it will subsequently be returned each time you try and instance it every time after that" from @Tim (a Realm guy).